# CardView size not dynamic when set to wrap_content

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I have a CardView for RecyclerView items that contains an ImageView and a LinearLayout (actionBar)

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/communityImageCv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    android:elevation="16dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/communityImageCl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/communityImageIv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/actionBar"
            tools:src="@drawable/person_splash_2" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:weightSum="3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/loveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/lovedIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/loved_heart_empty">

                </ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lovedText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/radikal"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:text="@string/love_this">

                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/shareButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:visibility="visible"

                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shareIcon"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/share_arrow_empty">

                </ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/sharedText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/radikal"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:text="@string/shared_this">

                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The LinearLayout is programmed to appear and disappear based on an attribute of the model. Afterward, the ImageView's height is changed programmatically based on another attribute (I'm only including this part in case it's relevant):

```
   fun bind(model: CommunityOffer) {

 if (model.isLikeable || model.isShareable) {
            actionBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        } else{
            actionBar.visibility = GONE

        }


        if (!model.mediaAspectRatio.isNullOrEmpty()) {

            val aspectRatioSplit = model.mediaAspectRatio.split(":")
            widthRatio = Integer.parseInt(aspectRatioSplit[0])
            heightRatio = Integer.parseInt(aspectRatioSplit[1])

            communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY

            height = ((width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()

            communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = height
            communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = height

            Glide.with(itemView.context).load(model.coverUrl).apply(RequestOptions().override(width, height).skipMemoryCache(true)).listener(requestListener).into(communityImageIv)

        } else {

            communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
            widthRatio = 25
            heightRatio = 21

            height = ((width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()

            communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = height
            communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = height

            Interactors.glide.loadImage(model.coverUrl, communityImageIv, requestListener)
        }
```

Rather than increasing in size to hold both of its child views, the CardView moves up the ImageView by in proportion to the size of the actionBar, cutting off the top of the ImageView:

Without actionBar:

[image]

With actionBar:

[image]

This looks how it's supposed to in the display panel of the .xml file, but not at run time. How do I make the CardView wrap its children appropriately at run time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with linear layout insted of constraintLayout as a child layout of cardView and than set your all child widgets in linearLayout i hope it might be work.

like this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/communityImageCv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    android:elevation="16dp">


 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/communityImageCl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           //set here your all child widgets 

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I've tried this, this actually makes it so that the actionBar does not appear at all, even if it is supposed to. It presumable gets cut off at the bottom. The problem seems to be with the card view being rigid.